# doing simply exercice with threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm doing my first exercise with threads and I can't get the objective. I need to print a loop like this

```
A
B
A
B
A...
```

I use two threads, one for printing A and the other for B. Adding a Static variable for change A and B.

The result is:

```
A
B
```

and sometimes:

```
A
B
A
```

What is the problem? I'm doing something bad, but I don't know.

### Code:

```
public class ExecucioThreads {
    public static boolean var;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new MeuThread_A().start();
        new MeuThread_B().start();

    }

}

public class MeuThread_A extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (true) {
            if (ExecucioThreads.var) {
                System.out.println("A");
                ExecucioThreads.var = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class MeuThread_B extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (true) {
            if (ExecucioThreads.var == false) {
                System.out.println("B");
                ExecucioThreads.var = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no guarantee in the order threads will run.

Comment: You have to synchronize the threads.

Comment: What happens if you add `volatile` to the declaration of the member variable `var`?

Comment: The exercise does not allow me to use Synchronized, only static variable.

Comment: With threads you never get precise output because of race conditions.  The whole point of threads is concurrent and independent operation for parallel processing.  If you want specific output then maybe you should reconsider using threads.

Comment: Then you need a lock to prevent race conditions.

Comment: Ok, Thank you nosid, I add volatile and now is running perfect : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you share memory between threads, there are a few things to consider. The *Java Memory Model* specifies the behaviour in detail. Fortunately, there is a very simple rule, which solves most problems with shared memory (JLS 17.4.5):

> [..] If all sequentially consistent executions are free of data races, [..] then all executions of the program will appear to be sequentially consistent.

In other words: Avoid *data races*. If there are no data races, then memory operations will do what most developers expect.

A *data race* exists, if a memory location might be accesses by two threads at the same time, at least one access is a write operation, and the memory location is not *volatile*. In your example, there is a data race on `var`. By declaring `var` as `volatile`, you remove the *data race*, and the program works.